# How to fetch all cookies from client computer using PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I can retrieve a Cookie value by:

```
<?php
$cookie=$_COOKIE["cookieName"]; 
?>
```

Now i want to fetch all cookies in client computer using php. I don't want their values i just want their names. Here my requirement is to know about client web activities in specific recent visited websites . I just googled it says we cant access to other domains cookies .Any way just want to know is there any way to fetch all recent visited websites from client computer? Thanks.

Comment: I don't want you to access all the cookies in my browser, not even simply by name; and I'm not a fan of your trawling my browser history for stuff that doesn't concern you

Comment: **NO**. This is a basic security constraint. People wont want you to have this information anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you imagine the security implications if you could do that?

The best you can do is get all cookies that are sent to your domain, with `array_keys($_COOKIE)`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the basic concepts of cookies is that they are only sent to their respective domains. You cannot access all cookies, only those which belong to your site.